OpenCV in C++, error loading .dll libraries: libstdc++-6.dll: cannot open shared object file
(Note, I'm using MSYS2 on Windows 11. I haven't had any issues with includes or libraries until trying to use OpenCV.)
I'm trying to use OpenCV for a C++ project. In my IDE, I added the relevant include paths and it successfully recognises the header, allows autocomplete of OpenCV keywords, etc.
I can compile the project, but when I try and run it, I get this error:
$ ./testing_2.exe
C:/msys64/home/My Name/msys2-repos/project_folder/build/testing.exe: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++-6.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

As a quick fix I tried manually copying the .dll into the build/ dir, but when I do this more .dll files appear with the same error... eventually, it just says error while loading shared libraries: ?
Interestingly, when I do the following command ldd ./testing.exe, the .dll files all seem to be found!
other .dll files ...
libwinpthread-1.dll => /mingw64/bin/libwinpthread-1.dll (0x7ff85d980000)
libopencv_core-410.dll => /mingw64/bin/libopencv_core-410.dll (0x7fffd9210000)
libopencv_highgui-410.dll => /mingw64/bin/libopencv_highgui-410.dll (0x7ff849d30000)
libopencv_imgcodecs-410.dll => /mingw64/bin/libopencv_imgcodecs-410.dll (0x7ff849ca0000)
libstdc++-6.dll => /mingw64/bin/libstdc++-6.dll (0x7fffefbe0000)
... and so on

I've tried explicitly adding the OpenCV path to .bashrc, but this hasn't helped. I am a bit stuck here..

on Windows, you'd want to use a native environment, which means MSVC. some people choose MinGW, which is also "native", but OpenCV doesn't make binary releases for MinGW. the MSYS2 environment is entirely off the beaten path. you should expect everything to be extra hard.

why not just install WSL2 and an Ubuntu guest, and do your stuff in there, or remove Windows entirely since you don't want to use it

It's peculiar that you are launching testing_2.exe while the error is reported by testing.exe. Such errors will show up if the binary 'testing.exe' is not properly rebuilt against the dll's for that arch / build / platform / target. My guess is to check if everything is being properly build and linked with the correct flags - if you dislike the WSL option, building on Windows native or a native Linux dist double boot is another option.

Are you running your code in one of the msys2 terminals linke mingw64 or ucrt64? Did you use pacman to install opencv?

@ChristophRackwitz Unfortunately the project involves WinAPI and an app that is Windows only... thought MSYS2 would help me acclimatise

The solution turned out to be twofold:

I hadn't correctly added the environment variable.

After fixing that, I ended up at the error while loading shared libraries: ? error I mentioned above.

To fix that, I used Dependency Walker, and found that a couple random .dll files which an OpenCV .dll depended on weren't being found. I reinstalled them manually and all was fixed!

